# php switch statement error on int = 0

Tags: php, switch-statement

I am having a problem in php switch case.

When i set **$number=0** it should run very first **case** but here this code returns **10-20K** that is in second case.

I checked comparison operators, tested them in if else case they return correct values but here first case do not run on **$number=0**

Why is this happening ? php consider 0 as false or something wrong in code ?

Link to codepad paste http://codepad.org/2glDh39K

also here is the code

```
<?php

$number = 0;

    switch ($number) {
     case ($number <= 10000):
            echo "0-10K";
           break;
        case ($number > 10000 && $number <= 20000):
            echo "10-20K";
            break;
        case ($number > 20000 && $number <= 30000):
            echo "20-30K";
            break;
        case ($number > 30000 && $number <= 40000):
            echo "30-40K";
            break;
        case ($number > 40000 && $number <= 50000):
            echo "40-50K";
            break;
        case ($number > 50000 && $number <= 60000):
            echo "50-60K";
            break;
        case ($number > 60000 && $number <= 70000):
            echo "60-70K";
            break;
        case ($number > 70000 && $number <= 80000):
            echo "70-80K";
            break;
        case ($number > 80000 && $number <= 90000):
            echo "80-90K";
            break;
        case ($number > 90000):
            echo "90K+";
            break;

        default: //default
            echo "N/A";
            break;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
switch ($number) {
 case ($number <= 10000):   // check $number == ($number <= 10000)
       echo "0-10K";
       break;
 // you hit the below because `0 == false` is true in php
 case ($number > 10000 && $number <= 20000): // check $number == ($number > 10000 && $number <= 20000)
        echo "10-20K";
        break;
 // ...
```

But you could do it with less code:

```
function showRange($number) {
    if ($number > 90000) {
       echo "90K+";
       return;
    }
    echo sprintf("%s-%sK", (int) ($number / 10000) * 10, ((int) ($number / 10000) +1) * 10 );
}
```

Comment: More simple? Doesn't look like it to me. Less code - yes, but readability suffers here.

Comment: @Lix Ok, it's just about personal taste.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh: Because sometimes, one line isn't descriptive, and in 3, 4, 5 months, you won't know what this code does at all.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - Yeah right, but I think this is what comments are used for in programming languages.

Answer (score 7):

You are *almost* using the `switch` in reverse, but not quite. You need to either go fully into reverse by writing `switch(true)`:

```
switch (true) { // IMPORTANT CHANGE HERE!
    case ($number <= 10000):
        echo "0-10K";
       break;
    case ($number > 10000 && $number <= 20000):
        echo "10-20K";
        break;
    // etc
}
```

or otherwise change the whole thing to `if`/`else`:

```
if ($number <= 10000) {
    echo "0-10K";
else if ($number > 10000 && $number <= 20000) {
    echo "10-20K";
}
// etc
```

Two important notes:

1. Reverse `switch` usually looks terribly counter-intuitive the first time you see it. Please do not use it if you don't feel comfortable with it.
2. Your conditionals could be simplified -- assuming they appear in order, each `$number > X` part is made redundant by the fact that the check in the previous conditional (`$number <= X`) has already failed. However, it can be argued that keeping the checks makes the code more robust in the face of modification.

Answer (score 3):

When you execute a switch case method, you can't match against a boolean value like that. You need only compare the resulting value.

I think you should rewrite your code to use `if...then...elseif` statements.

```
if ($number <= 10000){
  echo "0-10K";
}elseif($number <= 20000){
  echo "10-20K";
}elseif($number <= 30000){
  echo "20-30K";
}elseif($number <= 40000){
  ...
}
```

By using this method you don't need to make two checks each time because the previous `if` statements check those conditions as well. IE: If you reach the second `if` statement, you already know that the value is **not** smaller than (or equal to) `1000` therefore it *must* be larger than `10000`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$number = 0;
var_dump($number); // int(0)
```

If you modify the statement to be `case ($number > 0 && $number <= 10000):`, it strangely works. But it works with any arbitrary lookup (`$number > 9091 && $number <= 10000`) entered.

Even with the complete bollock below:

```
$number = 0;
$jonskeet = false;

switch ($number)
{
    case ($jonskeet === true && $number <= 10000):
        echo "0-10K";
        // ...
```

It will output `0-10K` even though the same condition in an `if` statement won't work.

The problem is that `select` is not to be used with long conditionals. `select` can be used to do something if the value of a variable **is equal to** what is after the `case` keyword. See:

```
select ($user_rank)
{
    case 0:
        return "guest";
        break;
    case 1:
        return "user";
        break;
    // ...
    default:
        return "unknown";
        break;
}
```

But you have long conditions in the `case`s of your code.

```
case ($number <= 10000):
    echo "0-10K";
    break;
case ($number > 10000 && $number <= 20000):
    echo "10-20K";
    break;
```

Running this first translates `$number <= 10000` to *TRUE* and `$number > 10000 && $number <= 20000` to *FALSE*, like two statements. And after this, your code is executed in the manner below:

```
case TRUE:
    echo "0-10K";
    break;
case FALSE:
    echo "10-20K";
    break;
```

`$number` is `0`, but it can evaulate to `FALSE` too, this is why you get the not desired output.

As a solution, you should translate your code to have an `if`-`elseif`-`else` setup:

```
 if ( $number < 10000 ) {
     echo "0-10K";
 } else if ( $number > 10000 && $number <= 20000 ) {
     echo "10-20K";
 // ...
 } else {
     echo "N/A";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, if $i is equal to 0, PHP would execute all of the echo statements!

so its execute the statement of next case and in that case there is break so out from it

so use the if-else-if instead of switch case

```
if ($number <= 10000){
  echo "0-10K";
}elseif(  $number <= 20000){
  echo "10-20K";
}elseif(  $number <= 30000){
  echo "20-30K";
}elseif(  $number <= 40000){
  echo "90K+";
}

 ...

elseif(  $number <= 90000)
     echo "80-90K";

}elseif($number > 90000){
echo "90K+";
}
```

Comment: There is no need for those additional tests. If we have reached the second if statement, we already know that the value is larger than 10000...

Comment: @Lix my meaning is if in switch if there is 0 than all case will be execute

Comment: @hakra - first of all thanks for your answer :)

in switch if there is 0 it will execute 2nd case then     break;
because in first case it will check $number(0 act as false) == ($number <= 10000) (act as true) // so false == true // result false

similarly condition will become true in second thats why it was executing 2nd case.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for PHP `0` is `FALSE` (unless you use `===`). And yes, your code is incorrect - `switch` isn't for comparing ranges - it's for comparing values (at least in PHP, in Ruby or Perl 6 it's another matter), like there.

```
switch ($letter) {
case 'a':
    echo "A?";
    break;
default:
    echo "Unknown letter";
    break;
}
```

In your case, you compare number to conditions - those either return `true` or `false`. As `0` is `false`, the second condition catches. `switch` wasn't made for code like that, I would use `if` `else` instead or rewrite your logic - repeating isn't good idea.

```
$range_number = floor($number / 1000);
echo $range_number, $range_number ? "K" : "", "-", $range_number + 1, "K";
```

(by the way, I know that `switch (true)` works, but don't use it - it's ugly hack)

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do switch case for a range of number.Use if(){} else{} for this purpose.